# Access violation error in release mode

Tags: release, compatibility, release-mode

I had the following issue.
"I have released my c code successfully. But when i tried to run that .exe file, it is not responding. When i try to debug it using visual studio, It says "Access violation reading memory location". My code was running successfully in debug mode."
I tried all possible methods i knew, nothing worked and finally i tried "Troubleshoot compatibility" option. And to my surprise everything was working fine and good. My question is    will there be any compatibility issue when we release a project in visual studio? If so, how can we rectify it?

Comment: You'll need to show the code itself.

Comment: Sorry,Its a huge chunk of code, difficult to put it here.